# HTML Div set up

Tags: html, css, containers

I'm trying to do this:

```
|-----|----------------|
|  O  | OOO            |
|  O  |                |
| 50px|     300px      |
|  O  |                |
|  O  |                |
|  O  |                |
|-----|----------------|
```

A division(total width: 350px) divided into 2 (widths: 50px & 300px), then the 2nd division full of images 50widthx50height.

The O's represent a 50x50 image.

It seemed to have worked, but for some reason the images are overlapping by 50% or so. How do I do this right?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="right-container">
            <div class="object">
                <img src="img/tiles/wood.png">
            </div>
            <div class="object">
                <img src="img/tiles/wood.png">
            </div>
            <div class="object">
                <img src="img/tiles/wood.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}
#left {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}
#right {
position: relative;
width:300px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
}
#right-container {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
.object {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important change is to define a width for the images - see the last CSS rule in my example. Apart from that I took out a lot of unneccessary stuff.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#right {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8);
}

#right-container {}

.object {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.object img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="right-container">
      <div class="object">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/6bf">
      </div>
      <div class="object">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/bf6">
      </div>
      <div class="object">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/fc3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that was quick! I always have trouble when it comes to CSS, thank you! Also, is there a reason the `.object` class didn't automatically define the width/height of the image?

Comment: Or maybe.. I should've added the `.object` class to the `<img>` tag.. therefore only needing to do it your way with `#right-container img`?

Comment: images have their own width. If you don't bind that to the size of their container (as I did) or define px sizes, images will keep their original size

Comment: well - if the proportion isn't 1:1 (like 50:50), it would be distorted that way. So either width or height should be `auto` to keep the proportion

Comment: Thank you very much. I clearly see the problem now. The original image was 64x64, drawing onto a 50x50 positioning caused overlapping!

Comment: I'm sorry, one final question if it's ok. How would I make the images align center of the div if horizontal collumn not full? Thanks

Comment: in this case you'd have to erase the `float: left` and instead use `display: inline-block` on `.object`, and apply "text-align: center` to their container, i.e. to `#right-container`